# Why does DispatchQueue.sync cause Data race?

Tags: swift, multithreading, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-queue

Based on my printed output in the console window, the work in `que2` was only executed after the `que1` fully finished its work, so my question is why did I get the `Data race` warning even though the first block of work in `que1` was completely synchronous?

> Data race in closure #2 () -> () in BlankSwift at BlankSwift.porsche : BlankSwift.Car

```
struct Car {
  var name: String
}

let que1 = DispatchQueue(label: "que1", qos: .background)
let que2 = DispatchQueue(label: "que2", qos: .userInteractive)

var porsche = Car(name: "Porsche")

for i in 0...100 {
  que1.sync {
    porsche.name = "porsche1"
    print(porsche.name)
    porsche.name = "Porsche11"
    print(porsche.name)
    if i == 100 { print("returned ")}
  }

  que2.async {
     porsche.name = "porsche2"
     print(porsche.name)
     porsche.name = "Porsche22"
     print(porsche.name)
  }
}
```

Comment: In short, because (a) you are dispatching to your second queue asynchronously; and (b) you are doing this multiple times in the `for` loop. Thus, for any subsequent iteration of the `for` loop, code dispatched to the first queue may run in parallel with some block previously dispatched to the second queue in a prior iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `que1.sync` is indeed called synchronously, `que2.async` is asynchronous on a different queue, so it schedules its closure and immediately returns, at which point you go to the next iteration of the loop.

There is some latency before the `que2` closure begins executing.  So for example, the closure for `que2.async` that was scheduled for iteration 0, is likely to start executing while `que1.sync` is executing for some later iteration, let's say iteration 10.

Not only that, `que2` may well have multiple tasks queued up before the first one begins.  It's a serial queue, because you didn't specify the `.concurrent` attribute, so you don't have to worry about `que2` tasks racing on another `que2` closure access of `porsche.name` , but they definitely can race on `que1` closure accesses.

As for output ordering, ultimately the output will go to `FileHandle.standardOutput` to which the OS has a buffer attached, and you don't know what kind of synchronization scheme the OS uses to order writes to that buffer.  It may well use it's own call to `DispatchQueue.async` to ensure that I/O is done in a sensible way, much the way UI updates on AppKit/UIKit have to be done on the main thread.